# OpenWRT firewall package

Tags: firewall, iptables, openwrt

I'm new to OpenWRT. I read that firewall3 (fw3) is the default app that works with UCI and it is some kind of wrapper for iptables.

On my SDK, through menuconfig, I selected iptables and iptables6 but when I burn image on my device, fw3 is missing as also /etc/config/firewall and /etc/init.d/firewall.

What package do I need to install? In my menuconfig there I didn't find any package named fw3.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install `firewall` package (located in `Base System` section)

Comment: Thanks. I never guessed that it was there since there is Network section. Silly question, but I'm a newbie.